# Create relation between view and table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, model, entity-framework-core

My goal is to download items using EF Core from the database view, where I will join the table via `.Include` without foreign keys.

Structure of view:

```
SELECT Id, ArticleId, Code, Name 
FROM dbo.ArticleView
```

Structure of table:

```
SELECT Id, ArticleId, ImageName, ImageExtension 
FROM dbo.ArticleImages
```

I want to get date using ex. in C#:

```
_repository.GetAll().Include(x => x.Images).ToList();
```

Is it possible?

I don't want to for each record to download photos separately.

Comment: That should work fine.  Just configure the Entity Model as you would if ArticleView were a table.

Comment: Into ArticleView Model I should add ex. `public virtual ICollection<ArticleImage> Image { get;set; }` and this is enough?

Comment: You will need to map the foreign key properties explicitly if they don't follow the EF convention.  And you'll probably want to add the inverse navigation property to ArticleImage.